# Connecting to the Internet using Etisalat in Sri Lanka (Prolink PHS300) (Corporate Dongle)

Tags: 14.04, internet, 3g, wvdial, qt3

I live in Sri Lanka and my ISP is Etisalat Lanka PVT (LTD). I upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 a couple of weeks ago and I still am wondering how to connect to the Internet using my Etisalat Prolink PHS300 dongle. I have tried many online forums as well as Sakis3G but all of them are telling that they failed to connect. I got a 1kbps connection on the first day, and when I restarted my computer, it did not connect at all. In the inbuilt CD-ROM of the dongle there is some software but it will not install without `wvdial` and `qt3`. I do not have another Internet connection. I am dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows XP SP3. I have been using it with Windows for a long time with no problems, whatsoever. As soon as I tried to connect normally, it says "Network is disconnected"

My APN is "EBB" and my dial-up number is *99#

I have tried installing `wvdial` offline and it asks for some more expectancies such as

```
 a. libxplc; 
 b. libwvstreams-base; 
 c. libwvstreams-extras; 
 d. libuniconf;. 
 d. libaudio2; 
 e. libqt3-mt.
```

Sakis3G gave me a ray of hope but did not work.

I would appreciate any help provided. I hope my problem will be solved because I really like Ubuntu and wouldn't like to give up on it just because it can't connect to the Internet. My version of Windows is getting outdated and it is too expensive to upgrade and I don't want to use pirated versions.

Thanks in advance,

Sanoo

Comment: The link I got Sakis3G from is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mruu7dnza8ogmlz/sakis3g.tar.gz

Comment: I am wondering why no-one is answering? It is because my thread is no longer active? I would appreciate any answer to my question.

Comment: I had the same problem (Etisalat with Prolink PHS 300) but with Sakis3G it is working.

Comment: It might be because I am having a corporate dongle. I recently asked a service guy when I went in to one fo there shops recently and they told the APN is "internet" (not sure in caps or simple). I will try it out in my free time and post back.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's clear up, what the issue is exactly.
Ubuntu doesn't recognise your modem or it do recognise but didn't connect?

Anyways, if the s/w provided to you on CD-ROM is capable of running your modem on Ubuntu, but needs wvdial and qt3 only, then issue could be solved.

Do this:
1. Download following files: http://pastebin.com/JGVdXcAd

You can download them from anywhere. It will provide you wvdial and qt3.

1. Copy downloaded files to your 'home' folder.
2. Open terminal and type: sudo dpkg -i *.deb
3. Enter your password when prompted.

This will install wvdial and qt3 on your system. Hence, try installing your dongle's default application off CD-ROM to see it work.

Comment: It recognizes my dongle but tells me that network is disconnected just after telling me "GSM Network, You are now registered on home network". I went to the pastebin link but only got a .txt file with links. Should I download all 71 packages and manually install them? In the given software's tar.gz file there is an install.sh file which does not run in terminal but opens in gedit.

Comment: You may need to convert tar.gz to deb first, to install it.
However, you may run a .sh file in terminal by right clicking and selecting approppriate option.

Yes, you may need to download them all (use dta in firefox) and may install them all once through synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this solution for people who wouldn't find a solution for this issue in the web as I couldn't find one.
I had the same issue and solved it. I'm able to connect to the internet. But the method is not so simple. 
First you need to install sakis3g (search the web if you don't know the way)
Although sakis3g is supposed to work it didn't work for me so easy.
My 3g dongle was not even detected.

Once you plug in the dongle, start a terminal and get root access.

```
sudo -i
```

Then run sakis3g

```
sakis3g
```

A window will pop up and in that select "connect with 3g" to see whether it works.
If it doesn't come back to the same window and select "more options".
Then select "only  prepare modem(setup+...)".

Then another window will pop up and select "usb device" in that window.
Then select your dongle from the list.

You should get a message saying "Modem on /dev/tty...... registered to etisalat". Click ok and then select connect with 3g.

Then you will be asked to select your APN which for etisalat is wap.
Then enter a username and a password.

Comment: I am away from my computer with Ubuntu for a while. Will try it and get back to you as soon as possible.